# Jenkins Azure VM Agent: Environment variables

Tags: azure, jenkins

I've set up a Jenkins CI/CD on Azure using Azure VM agents to build my android application.

For the build agent I use a template that is an "Advanced Image Configuration" using the following Image Reference:

Canonical, UbuntuServer, 16.04-LTS, latest

In my Initialization Script I installed all required components to build my application (e.g. the android-sdk). It is run as Root, using sudo command for every operation.

The first time I launched my build it failed, because ANDROID_HOME was not defined. So I decided to add the Environment Injector Plugin to solve this.

**My Questions are:**

- Is it possible to define the ENV within the Initialization script too?
- Do I have to configure my agent in a different way?
- Will I have to create and configure a VM image and use that instead?

**Edit / Solution:**

```
sudo cat >> /etc/environment <<EOL
ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk
PATH=${PATH}:/opt/android-sdk/tools:/opt/android-sdk/tools/bin:/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools
EOL
```

This was successful thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. yeah, why not? just set an environment variable as part of your script.
2. not sure what you ask here, what do you want to achieve?
3. i dont like images, i prefer an automated way to create a working vm with scripts. but you can certainly do that

Comment: When adding this in the Initialization Script:

`export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk-linux`

It isn't available during build

Comment: well, you need to set it for all users, i would think, jenkins is probably running under its own user. take a look here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables

Comment: Thank you very much, see my Edit, this works great :)

Comment: in that case you should accept this answer as a proper one ;)